# What do you call someone who ‘makes a dictation’ or ‘dictates’?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I only found 'dictator', but even as a non-native-speaker I guess that is overly associated with 'tyrant' or 'despot'.

In my case I need someone who speaks into a microphone for text recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, but don't you want to have some fun? Just as someone who makes an allegation can be described as a allegator, can't you see the comedic opportunities in referring to this person as a dictator? :p

But seriously, as long as the context is clear, it's fine to call this person a [dictator](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dictator?s=t). It's common for words to have different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: Well said. :) Since we release our software almost exclusively to non-native-speakers, I thought that may could provoke some misunderstanding, but you convinced me to use it nevertheless.

Answer (score 4):

I would simply suggest

- speaker

because [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/speaker) says

> 1. a person who speaks.
> 2. a person who speaks formally before an audience; lecturer; orator.

Comment: Maybe my edit was bit too late, but I do not mean someone who speaks before an audience, but a person like a physicist speaking into a microphone for later transcription.

Comment: @Art1st - There are two entries for speaker, numbered 1 and 2. Number 2 might not fit your situation, nut number 1 definitely does.

Answer (score -2):

A person who dictates or take notes of something someone says is called an amanuensis

Comment: Hi Donald Wheeler! Welcome to English Language & Usage. We like to see answers with solid explanations and authoritative references. Perhaps you could edit your answer to provide more detail and some links to support it? Also, you might want to take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour)  and read through [the help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: It seems that an amanuensis always is an assistant, who writes down the speech of others. This wouldn't fit here. In this case it was asked for the person recording his own speech.

Comment: The question is asking about (a more modern version of) the _other_ person: the person who says the words the amanuensis writes down.